# How to configure endpoint for Saga when multiple consumer

Tags: masstransit

I need to configure endpoint on Saga 'Consumer' such as "queue:send-notification" to move from Publish to Send, because I have redundancy on my service (and right now) each email is sent twice.

How can I do that for both test:

```
 x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
 {
       cfg.UseInMemoryScheduler(out ISchedulerFactory factory); 
       _scheduler = factory.GetScheduler();
       cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox();
       cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
});
```

And

```
 x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                    {
                        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                        ...
                        cfg.UseMessageScheduler(schedulerEndpoint);
                        cfg.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Intervals(config.GetSection(RetryIntervalsKey).Get<int[]>()));
                        cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox();
                    });
```

Does the addition of

```
       EndpointConvention.Map<SendNotification>(new Uri("queue:send-notification"));
```

Is enough??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first, if you have a "redundancy" where you are using the same message type for two separate things, you should resolve that issue. Or if you have two consumers that are sending email notifications in response to the same event, fix that problem.

*The use of EndpointConvention is NEVER recommended.*

You can, however, use `.SendAsync()` from the saga, and pass the destination address as the first parameter so that the message is sent instead of using `.PublishAsync()`.

Though it seems like you have system design/architecture issues given the use of the same contract in multiple email delivery services.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for you rapid answer (as usual).    
Actually after testing some more, I found out that message aren't Consumed twice (or more) when I have multiple instance of the same SagaStateMachine listening in parallel. They actually seem to do a 'round-robin' (or this I what I deducted, when I connect my local machine to the queue in debug, I get 1 out of 3 Command dispatch to my computer).  
Is this the expected behavior?  
I've remove every EndpointConvention code related lines... Hence, i'm unto the out-of-the-box behavior.    
Sorry for waisting your time.